# How to check if a "start time" is not later than "end time" in PHP

Tags: php, time, timestamp, compare

I'm trying to check if a specific "start time" is not later than another "end time"

For exemple :
Start : 09:00 and End : 11:00 is OK
Start : 10:00 and End : 08:00 is NOT OK

If the "end time" is midnight (00:00), so it's ok because :
Start : 08:00 and End : 00:00 is OK

I managed to do this little function, and it works as I want :

```html
<?php

function isTimeOk($start, $end) {
    if (($start < $end) or $end == '00:00') {
        return 'Ok';
    }

    return 'Not ok';
}

echo isTimeOk('09:00', '12:00');

?>
```

But, I've two questions :

Is there a way to make this code more elegant?
How to make this compatible with the 12 and 24 hour format?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Try to compare time in milliseconds you can use `strtotime` for it

Comment: @Rabby Indeed, it solve the 12/24hours format. But, not if "end time" is midnight

Comment: If your considering midnight it should be `24:00`  but I am not getting why `00:00`.

Comment: @Rabby Yeah, I know that doesn't make much sense. But I have to take the data from an existing MySQL database and the format is from 00:00 to 23:59 (24hours format). So that this function can be useful to me later, I would also like it to be compatible in 12h format

Comment: @Rabby It may be different in other parts of the world, but in Europe midnight is universally represented as 00:00, never 24:00, and only very rarely as 12:00

Comment: Note that to support 12-hour clock you need to define acceptable notations: "10:30 pm"? "10:30 PM"? "10:30p"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

function isTimeOk($start, $end) {
    $start  = strtotime($start);
    $end    = strtotime($end);
    
    if (($start < $end) or $end == strtotime('00:00')) {
        return 'Ok';
    }

    return 'Not ok';
}
echo isTimeOk('09:00', '12:00');
?>
```

strtotime should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use timestamps or convert the time to DateTime:

```php
function isTimeOk(string $start, string $end): bool {
    if ($end == '00:00') {
        return true;
    }

    $start_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $start);
    $end_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $end);
    
    return $start_date < $end_date;
}
```

For more information on time format (including 12/24 clock), visit https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Yes, It works also, but still not if end time is midnight (00:00)

Comment: I guess it is sufficient to add `if ($end == '00:00') return true;`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Solution form @Sujit Bhise  works perfectly. Same as you suggested. I can even mix start and end with 12 ou 24h format. Thank you all for your help !